# java: Как в рантайм узнать откуда в коде выполняется обращение к элементам определенного пакета?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Необходимо узнать в рантайме ***откуда*** выполняется обращение, к элементам определенного пакета (***com.data.* ***) и записать информацию в лог-файл.

В идеале по логом нужно будет понять ***откуда в коде вызывается метод*** любого класса из пакета **com.data.***

Было бы неплохо посмотреть пример AOP (Aspectj)
)

---

**UPD:**

Код который будет *вызываться* - модифицировать нельзя, как и тот код, который будет *вызывать* (поэтому я смотрю в стороны Aspectj)

---

На текущий момент есть идея:
натравить Aspectj на пакет ***com.data*** и выдавать advice с записью в лог файл при обращении к пакету, а имя, вызывающего класса, брать из стэка вызова метода

по поводу производительности - пока не переживаем...
Понятно, что это не увеличит производительность...
Возможно, чтобы снизить нагрузку записи в файл - буду кэшировать названия вызывающих классов и методов и фильтровать их при выдаче advice.

Comment: если код можете изменять, т.е. ваш код, добавьте в нужное место логгер с эмулированной ошибкой, которая покажет StackTrace

Comment: Готовы к тому, что это сделает ваш код очень медленным?

Comment: @Dred, к сожалению это не просто отладочная задача...  выбрасывать исключение или логировать все вызовы - нельзя. Суть в том, чтобы накопить инфу за какой-то период времени и использовать ее при выпиливании легаси кода..

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, я не готов.. но это необходимость.. если есть наименее затратный по производительности метод, чем я описал в обновлении вопроса - рад буду воспользоваться советом.

Comment: @ВиталийВихляев попробуйте лучше Java Flight Recorder использовать.

Comment: @Dred а зачем исключение использовать ? Можно так : "Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();"

Comment: Да, неплохой вариант,скорее всего лучше моего.